# What is the schema for streaming data into Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to stream JSON data into BigQuery. Its [Example from Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/loading-data-into-bigquery), they ask for a Schema file in code

```
  url = "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/bigquery/v2/projects/" + projectId + "/jobs"
  newSchemaFile = raw_input("What is your schema? ")
  schema = open(newSchemaFile, 'r')
```

what is the format for this schema file. I can't seem to find any information on it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample schema for a 4 column table:

```
          [
            {
              'name': 'Name',
              'type': 'STRING'
            },
            {
              'name': 'Age',
              'type': 'INTEGER'
            },
            {
              'name': 'Weight',
              'type': 'FLOAT'
            },
            {
              'name': 'IsMagic',
              'type': 'BOOLEAN'
            }
          ]
```

Comment: How about nulls in a column ?